# Kafka ACL: wildcard(*) suffixed topic name support

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

I am following the https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html#adding-or-removing-a-principal-as-producer-or-consumer for adding ACL's to my Kafka cluster.

As per above doc, we can add ACL with prefixed topic name, like:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \ 
--add --allow-principal User:Jane --producer --topic Test- --resource-pattern-type prefixed
```

This allows User **Jane** to access all topics whose name start with **Test-**

What I am looking for is - can I do the same for topic name suffix? I mean How can I allow User **Jane** to access all topics whose name end with **_Test**

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Currently the modes available are - liternal, prefix only. I was unable to achieve this, so I changed the topic names

Comment: Ok, was hoping for a hack :P Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the options of `--resource-pattern-type` there is not a `suffix`, [but there is  a `match` or `literal`](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/resource/PatternType.html).

Perhaps you can try using something like `'*_Test'` with one of those options.

Comment: Match is only for listing ACLs. The only modes available for creating them are "literal" and "prefix"